# Что означает слово "арборесцентность"?

Tags: заимствования

Что означает слово "арборесцентность" и какие у него антонимы?

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, где вы такое нашли... Наверное, существительное от ***арборесцентный***. Это из языка геммологов (специалистов по камням-самоцветам).

> Арборесцентный - древообразный, напоминающий ветви дерева.

http://malagavista.blogspot.ru/2012/01/blog-post_573.html